# Useful program to render CSS in different browsers instead of installing each one separately?

Tags: css, browser, installation, render

In order to test CSS in different browsers, do I have to result to installing each browser on my development system? Isn't there a useful program where you can just load an html+css file and view how it's rendered in different modern browsers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, you have to have those browsers installed in some form, although there is software such as IE Tester which will allow you to open tabs as IE5.0 - IE8. There are also online services such as:

- https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.htm

  - Free Service
  - Limited # of browsers Available
- http://crossbrowsertesting.com

  - Paid Service
- http://browsershots.org/

  - Free Service
  - Supports INSANE # of browsers
  - It can take a long time - I've had it take an hour to return screen shots during peak usage. Can be as fast as 2 minutes for a dozen browsers.

Which will let you view your site in multiple browsers.

Comment: Also note that browsershots.org is open source, so you can run [your own server](http://code.google.com/p/browsershots/wiki/DistributedArchitecture). You still need actual browser installations though.

Answer (score 5):

If you're after a professional solution, take a look at [Litmus](http://litmusapp.com/).

Comment: I *knew* I was forgetting one, I could even remember what the site looked like, just not the name!

Comment: Thanks, although I was looking for a free software. They offer a 50/tests per month free plan, which is unfortunately well below what I need.

Comment: Is this a hobby thing? Do you really need more than 50/month? If it's professional you can't afford $39-49?

Comment: +1 - As a point of interest, the folks to run **Litmus also run DocType.com** and have an **affiliation with Stack Overflow** (see the footer links below): http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/08/stack-overflow-and-doctype/

Comment: the adobe link I gave below is a free service.

Comment: @cletus, the problem with the free 50/month plan is that it only includes 2 browsers (Explorer 7 and Firefox 2).  I do agree that for a professional, the $50 plan pays for itself in time saved checking things manually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 3 engines in one browser check [Lunascape](http://www.lunascape.tv/).
Additionally for all Internet Explorer versions you have [IEtester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).